# Xcode 7.1 Allocations Instrument SIP Throws a fit

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

Do I have to turn off System Integrity Protection to run allocations on the simulator? I'm wondering if anyone else is having this issue on Xcode 7.1?

[image]

Comment: Apple says: "System Integrity Protection does not prevent you from inspecting your own apps when you’re developing them. You can continue to use Instruments and LLDB to profile and debug apps built with Xcode." If that's not true, file a bug.

Comment: @matt I've filed a radar already. I'm wondering if it's something others are experiencing.

Comment: Understood. I'm just saying you're on firm ground (which at first I failed to understand), because Apple has a document that specifically says you're supposed to be able to do what you're trying to do. And that's the Simulator — does it work on the device, at least?

Comment: I will do some experimenting. I have another Mac here. I just updated to the latest El Cap too.

Comment: I am receiving the exact same warning trying to run Allocations on my Macbook > Safari. I have El Cap running Xcode/Instruments v7.2.1. When I try Allocations on my connected iPad (iOS 9.2.1) I get a different error: 'Unable to attach to task; port invalid'. What is the solution?

Comment: @MacMadIll Did you look at my answer to this issue below? I see you disabled System Integrity Protection. You shouldn't be doing that. It has to do with what device you're trying to run it on. Don't run it on an external device or simulator. It should default to the right place. Don't touch the Target dropdown when you first launch it and you should be good.

Answer (score 3):

I heard back from Apple today. If you look at the image I am running the simulator itself in instruments, rather than my app inside the simulator! Thought I'd post a follow up just in the unlikely event somebody else stumbles into this blunder.

Answer (score 1):

No.  You do not need to disable SIP for development with the Simulator (or any other part of Xcode).

Comment: I know it seems strange. Are you able to run allocations with 7.1 with SIP on?

Comment: Yep.  I just tested right now.  I was able to run it in Xcode 7.1 with SIP on.

Comment: Thanx for testing it out for me. I've been updating another machine to run some tests. One thing I will try is turning SIP off, running allocations and if it runs try to turn it back on.