# Receiving error 'Unable to attach to task; port invalid' when trying to run Xcode 7 Instruments, Allocations/Leaks tool on connected iPad

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, memory-leaks, mobile-safari

I have Macbook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012) and it is running El Capitan v.10.11.3.

I have connected an iPad 2 running iOS 9.2.1.

I am attempting to run Xcode 7's Instruments app and select the Leaks or Allocations tool. My target is iPad > MobileSafari or iPad > Web (Standalone mode).

Once I click the record button I receive the following error 'Unable to attach to task; port invalid.'

I also tried this on the iPad Air running iOS 8.3 and received the error 'Failed to attach to target process.'

When I tried running Leaks on my Macbook > Safari. I received the error 'Failed to attach: Target process is marked restricted, cannot be traced while System Integrity Protection is enabled' 
Related to: [Xcode 7.1 Allocations Instrument SIP Throws a fit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33308335/xcode-7-1-allocations-instrument-sip-throws-a-fit)

I was able to disable SIP (by running 'csrutil disable; reboot' in the Terminal when my Macbook was in recovery mode) and now the Leaks tool is working on my Macbook but I still cannot figure out how to run Leaks on an iPad's MobileSafari app.

Is anyone else having this issue and how can I fix it?

I have searched through the Instruments help docs but cannot find anything.

[image: Xcode Leaks > iPad > Unable to attach to task; port invalid.]

Comment: Did you find the answer to this problem? I am having the same here

Comment: I am also coming up against this same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this thread on Apple Devs](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/61088)

> Profiling system applications is restricted. You'll only be able to profile applications you built and installed from Xcode.

So apparently, you can't use Instruments to do this.